# Datatable does not show excel button

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables, export-to-excel

**I use data table jquery  but datatable does not show export buttons here is my code
here is my view code**  i use jquery script

```
 success: function (data) {
                    $('#datatablevalue').show();

                    var tabletools = $('#datatable7').dataTable({
                        
                        dom: 'Bfrtip',
                        buttons: [
                        //'copyHtml5',
                        //'excelHtml5',
                        {
                            extend: 'excelHtml5',
                            title: 'NothingToPrint Report'
                        },
                        //{
                        //    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        //    title: 'NothingToPrint Report'
                        //},
                        'pageLength'
                        //'csvHtml5',
                        //'pdfHtml5'
                    ],
                        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                        data: data,
                        columns: [

                            //{ 'data': 'CircleName' },
                            //{'data':'Region'},
                            { 'data': 'KioskId' },
                            { 'data': 'BranchAddress' },
                            { 'data': 'Status' },
                            { 'data': 'UpdateDownfrom' },
                            { 'data': 'LastTranscation' },
                            { 'data': 'Reason' }
                        ]
                    });
```

**and my scripts library are**
please suggest solution  am trying to add buttons to the datatable but it dose not shows

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I created a simple table using your script resources, and your (edited down) DataTable definition. I added the DataTables CSS resource, and I used some hard-coded HTML data for testing (so no ajax/JSON). The Excel button was displayed correctly.Maybe you can try doing the same - and then make additional changes to transform my working test case to your target solution - and see exactly when the problem appears. Or, you can provide a [mre] for us.

Comment: Minor note: You are using `$('#datatable7').dataTable(...)`. This is out-of-date and you should probably be using `DataTable(...)` instead of `dataTable(...)`. You can read about the difference between these 2 syntaxes [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/). I do not think this is relevant to your button issue, however.